# Centering a vertically oriented button in a rowspan cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a vertically oriented button that has to be centered laterally an vertically in a rowspan cell. Now the button touches the left border of the cell. It is positioned vertically in the middle.

I get some space between the cell border and the button by using padding-left, but this is NOT my preferred way.

[Codepen of the problem](https://codepen.io/Tissi_2/pen/VgrJGL)

I expect the exact middle position of the button within the `<td class="range_supervisor" rowspan="4">`.

Comment: Are you talking about maybe using `margin: auto;` in the `.short` class ? I can't quite understand what you're trying to achieve : Something like this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJyOab - remove the width on your first `td` of `25%` too...

Comment: Add this to the CSS: `td { border: 1px solid lightgrey; }` and you will see the button is already centered vertically in the cell.

Comment: Any particular reason why you have the `writing-mode` on the td rather than the button? It works the way you want if you move it to the button. https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/gqXVee

Comment: do You want supervisor button and then range 5 and blue border and then available?

Comment: Maybe you should post a screenshot of what it looks now, because it seems the commenters don't see the same output you see.

Comment: Mr. Lister has already posted the solution. Moving the `writing-mode` to the button did the trick. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Lister has found the solution to my question. Moving the `writing-mode` to the button did exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

[CLOSED]